# Parsley custom validator is not working

Tags: javascript, parsley.js

so I have this custom validator which for testing reasons should always return false:

```
$(document).ready(function(){   

  $('#new_user').parsley({
    validators: {
      urlasemail: function () {
        return {
          validate: function ( val, emailField ) {
            alert('good');
            return false;
          }
        };
      }
    }
  });

});
```

And the form field looks like this:

```
<input class="string url required" id="something" name="website" parsley-error-message="" parsley-trigger="keyup" parsley-urlasemail="nothing" placeholder="mywebsite.com" size="50" type="text">
```

When I don't specify a priority for the validator as above then I get a console log saying that validator "urlasemail" has default priority.

So for some reason it looks like the JS is fine but it just doesn't want to validate...

Answer (score 0):

It seems that even if console log telling default priority is applied, custom validators without priority are not working.

Here, [On this jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/F9q4r/) I've set a 512 priority and it is well fired:

```
$('#new_user').parsley({
validators: {
  urlasemail: function () {
    return {
      validate: function ( val, emailField ) {
        alert('foo');
        return false;
      },
        priority: 512
    };
  }
}
```

});

Best

Comment: It doesn't work for me... I solved it by using extend like in the parsley.extend.js

Comment: Carful when using custom options in javascript, be sure to remove the parsley-validate directive on your form, and do it manually in javascript (there is a small warning about that in the doc)

Comment: I did this... so all other validations work fine, but just the custom one is not working. And this is all the code that I used...

Comment: For the basic settings it is really not working as @bresc commented. I opened new question with jsfiddle example here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24246098/parsley-custom-validator-is-not-working-for-javascript-installation