# Parsley custom validator is not working for javascript installation

Tags: parsley.js

I have the simplest possible form with the simplest custom validator and it is not working, see http://jsfiddle.net/M55M4/ What is wrong?

```html
<form id="myform">
    <input type="text" data-parsley-myvalidator="foo" data-parsley-required />
    <input type="submit" />
</form>
```

```js
$('#myform').parsley({
    validators: {
        myvalidator: function () {
            return {
                validate: function (value, requirements) {
                    alert('myvalidator');
                    return false;
                },
                priority: 32
            }
        }
    },
    messages: {
        myvalidator: 'my validator failed'
    }
});
```

Answer (score 13, accepted):

If Parsley js version is not critical I recommend you to update it to the latest one - [v.2.0.2](http://parsleyjs.org/dist/parsley.min.js).
According to the new API, custom validator should be defined the following way (http://jsfiddle.net/M55M4/6/):

```js
window.ParsleyValidator.addValidator('myvalidator', 
function (value, requirement) {
    alert('myvalidator');
    return false;
}, 32)
.addMessage('en', 'myvalidator', 'my validator failed');
```

Comment: No offense meant to the maintainer of this lib, as it's a useful one for sure, but the docs seem to be lacking in ensuring they're up-to-date. This SO answer helped me more than the official docs did.

Comment: When implementing this myself just now, I found that using all-lowercase for the validator name is needed (I'm on 2.1.2) as suggested by the answer. It appears that something like `myValidator` won't work even if you define it the same in the `addValidator()` and `addMessage()` calls, due to some internal issues w/Parsley. Specifically, `addMessage` converts the name to all-lowercase (like `myvalidator`), but its internal `getErrorMessage` continues looking for a camel-cased version (like `myValidator`).

Comment: Huge thank you for the lowercase hint. It was a very well hidden problem. As stated in the first comment, the docs does not help much on this one.

Comment: No need to lowercase validator name - just use it kebab-cased, e.g.  `myValidator` => `data-parsley-my-validator />`

Comment: This is no longer valid, Please see answer by Andrey

Answer (score 4):

Accepted answer is deprecated now.

> Accessing the method 'addValidator' through ParsleyValidator is
>   deprecated. Simply call 'window.Parsley.addValidator

Example of custom validator: date format validation dd/mm/yyyy with momentJS:

```
<input type="text" required="" data-parsley-dateformat="date" />

window.Parsley.addValidator('dateformat', {
    validate: function(value, id) {
        var isValid = moment(value, "DD/MM/YYYY", true).isValid();
        return isValid;
    },
    messages: {
        en: 'Please provide date in format dd/mm/yyyy'
    }
})
```

This example for Parsley v 2.6.0 on plunker:
http://plnkr.co/edit/hYDd19uPbJzKRVf9IMsH?p=preview